# I can't change the text of tab bar controller 8 items (after More button) using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I added a tab bar controller of 8 items, but the system adds the 'more' button for me.
The problem is I can't change the title of tab bar item 5 and 'more'.
Here is the error message. I have confirmed that I have 8 Items.

**Code :**

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.items![5].title = "ok"
```

**Error**

```
Thread 1: Exception: "*** __boundsFail: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureViewControllers()
    }

    private func configureViewControllers() {
        let colors: [UIColor] = [.systemRed, .systemBlue, .systemGray, .systemTeal, .systemPink]
        var vcs = [UIViewController]()
        for i in 0...6 {
            let vc = UIViewController()
            vc.view.backgroundColor = colors.randomElement()!
            vc.tabBarItem.title = "VC \(i)"
            vcs.append(vc)
        }
        viewControllers = vcs
    }
}
```

So you have to set the titles of the view controllers via `vc.tabBarItem.title = "your title"` or you can set them even inside of your view controllers `viewDidLoad()` with `tabBarItem.title = "..."`. 
For further reading: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller

Comment: Did you try to set your tabBarItem title via ```tabBarItem.title = "myTitle"``` inside of ```viewDidLoad()``` of your view controller (which is presented by your tabBarController) as described above?

Comment: Yes , it work for Items 0..4 but not working in item > = 5 :(

Comment: for the 4 first items , it work but the next of items after more button not working : 
Exemple  print(tabBarItem.title) return nil